# How to use csrf_token in Django RESTful API and React?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have previous experience in `Django`. If add line `{csrf_token}` in `Django` templates then `Django` handles the  functionalities of `csrf_token`. But when I am trying to develop an API using `Django REST Framework` then I get stuck. How can I add and handle functionalities like `csrf_token` in `API` (back end, developed using `Django REST Framework`) and `React Native/React JS` (front end) like Django templates?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The first step is to get CSRF token which can be retrieved from the Django csrftoken cookie.

Now from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/) you can find out how to get the csrf token from the cookie by using this simple JavaScript function:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Now, you can retrieve the CSRF token by calling the `getCookie('csrftoken')` function

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Next you can use this csrf token when sending a request with fetch() by assigning the retrieved token to the X-CSRFToken header.

```
  fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    },
    body: {}
   })
  }
```

**Rendering the CSRF Token in React Forms:**

If you are using React to render forms instead of Django templates you also need to render the csrf token because the Django tag `{ % csrf_token % }` is not available at the client side so you need to create a higher order component that retrieves the token using the `getCookie()` function and render it in any form.

Lets add some line in `csrftoken.js` file.

```
import React from 'react';

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

const CSRFToken = () => {
    return (
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={csrftoken} />
    );
};
export default CSRFToken;
```

Then you can simply import it and call it inside your form

```
import React, { Component , PropTypes} from 'react';

import CSRFToken from './csrftoken';


class aForm extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
                 <form action="/endpoint" method="post">
                        <CSRFToken />
                        <button type="submit">Send</button>
                 </form>
        );
    }
}

export default aForm;
```

**The Django CSRF Cookie**

React renders components dynamically that's why Django might not be able to set a CSRF token cookie if you are rendering your form with React. This how Django docs says about that:

> If your view is not rendering a template containing the csrftoken
> template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. This is
> common in cases where forms are dynamically added to the page. To
> address this case, Django provides a view decorator which forces
> setting of the cookie: ensurecsrf_cookie().

To solve this issue Django provides the ensurecsrfcookie decorator that you need to add to your view function. For example:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def myview(request):
```

Comment: I have used this: var cookie = cookies[i].toString().replace(/^([\s]*)|([\s]*)$/g, "");   instead of var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);   this way you don't need jQuery

Comment: `cookies[i].trim()` is better, whould be nice if you can edit your post :)

Comment: i am using react js as frontend and django just for backend apis. the html of react js is rendered by react js itself, django just provides the json data on calling its api. 

I saw the cookies on reactjs page after calling django apis, no cookies is set and why should it be set because django is just giving json data not setting cookies.

so how can i get the csrf cookie value in such case ?

Comment: @Yusuf did u find a solution for this? I'm also using react to render the pages

Comment: @Davi - either use csrf by https://fractalideas.com/blog/making-react-and-django-play-well-together-single-page-app-model/ or switch to token based authentication with django knox which is better than default token auth by django rest and also closer to real world apis https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox

Comment: For token based you get a auth token on login save it and use it for any other apis by passing in header, once logout the token stays invalid

Comment: https://github.com/mir1198yusuf/feedapp_django_restapi_reactjs see my sample repo also see api docs in readme

Comment: @Yusuf, Does Knox authentication solve the issues of CSRF token from React? If we use Knox, do we still need to pass CSRF token ?

Comment: Yes it solves. We need to pass Knox auth token in header during api call. If you see my React code in above repo, I have added authorisation header while axios api call

Comment: We dont need to pass CSRF token anymore since our api now authenticates using auth token. So api becomes auth token based instead of CSRF. Other folks at SO can explain better if you ask a new question like what is diff between CSRF and auth token based

Comment: @Yusuf If you want to store token in cookies (like storing jwt refresh token in cookies), you still need to use csrf tokens to protect it.

Comment: @orvi It means that we have to create a view, which creates and sets a csrf token as cookie, and do that request before submitting every form? Then how does the django can figure out who has obtained that csrf token originally? Maybe a malicious user can do a request to that endpoint, capture a valid token, and add it to the form, to modify information of another user!

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery for ajax in react, so in this case here is a solution :

```
let csrfcookie = function() {  // for django csrf protection
            let cookieValue = null,
                name = "csrftoken";
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
                let cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    let cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + "=")) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
};

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       beforeSend: function(request, settings) {
                    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrfcookie());
                    }
},

.... /// other codes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle CSRF token protection in your Django RESTful API and React application by using the `django-react-csrftoken` library. This library simplifies the process of including CSRF tokens in your React forms and communicating securely with your Django backend.

You can install `django-react-csrftoken` in your React project using npm:

```bash
npm install --save django-react-csrftoken
```

In your React component, you can use the `DjangoCSRFToken` component to include the CSRF token within your form:

```bash
import React from 'react';
import DjangoCSRFToken from 'django-react-csrftoken';

class MyLoginForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form>
          <DjangoCSRFToken /> {/* Include the CSRF token */}
          {/* Other form fields (e.g., email, password) */}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

To ensure that the CSRF token is set in the response cookies for views that render forms in Django, you can use the `@ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator:

```bash
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def register_view(request):
    # Your view logic here
```

For more detailed information and examples, you can refer to the official [django-react-csrftoken GitHub](https://github.com/iMerica/django-react-csrftoken/blob/master/README.md) repository. The repository's README provides comprehensive documentation on how to use the library effectively.